# Bad bind variable error in Oracle 10g developer form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have created a table named password

```
CREATE TABLE PASSWORD (USER_ID NUMBER(10)  CONSTRAINT  PASSWORD_USER_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
PASSWD   VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO PASSWD (USER_ID,PASSWD) VALUES (1,100);
INSERT INTO PASSWD (USER_ID,PASSWD) VALUES (2,200);
```

And created a Login form in an Oracle form developer 10g. And I used this code into Login button.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR login_cursor IS
      SELECT user_id,
             passwd
      FROM   password;
    user_id_var password.user_id%TYPE;
    passwd_var  password.passwd%TYPE;
    login_flag  BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
    OPEN login_cursor;

    <<check_records>>
    LOOP
        FETCH login_cursor INTO user_id_var, passwd_var;

        IF( :login_user_id = user_id_var
            AND :login_passwd = passwd_var ) THEN
          Message('You are in');

          login_flag := TRUE;

          exit check_records;
        END IF;

        EXIT WHEN login_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE login_cursor;

    IF( NOT login_flag ) THEN
      Message('INVALID LOGIN');
    END IF;

    clear_form;
END;
```

But error message appeared like

```
bad bind variable 'login_user_id'
bad bind variable 'login_passwd'
```

What's the solution for this?

Comment: I hope that's not used in production anywhere.. plaintext password storage, *shudders* .. also your login check logic is weird.. why are you going through *all* records in table instead of checking for the specific username?

Comment: I agree with @Sathya. Not only weird, but slow and unsecure.

Answer (score 1):

Form variables are referenced using `:block_name.item_name`. You're using `:login_user_id` which seems to be missing the reference to block, hence Forms is not able to reference the variable and seems to thing it's a bind variable, which it's not.

Correct the syntax referencing the variables

Comment: I wanna use this code. Please help me to complete my task. 
DECLARE
v_exist number;
BEGIN
SELECT 'x'
INTO v_exist
FROM password
WHERE user_id = :user_id 
AND passwd = :passwd;

GO_ITEM('new_block.new_item');

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
MESSAGE('loginid or password error');
clear_form;
END;

Comment: so what's preventing you from using it?